# Determine if windows needs Reboot/Restart Programmatically

Tags: c#, windows, registry, restart, reboot

I am looking for a way to determine if windows needs to reboot or restart inside a C# application. For example, because a newly installed app needs windows to restart. What are available solutions for this?

Comment: What do you mean by need ? When is your need for restart ?

Comment: There is no API to set nor query this AFAIK.

Comment: For example, I installed an application, and the installation requires the windows to restart, and I postponed the restarting for later. I want to determine if the windows requires such reboot/restart programmatically

Comment: Is it *your* program that is causing the other application to install? If so, the return code from msiexec or other moral equivalents should tell you that a restart is required. If not, why is your program fussing about this?

Comment: The following may be helpful: [EventLog Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog?view=netframework-4.8). In Windows, open Control Panel => Administrative Tools =>  Event Viewer. Look under "Windows Logs" => "Setup". Here's an example message: _A reboot is necessary before package KB5015730 can be changed to the Installed state._ To read the message in code, use the previously mentioned class.

Comment: https://adamtheautomator.com/pending-reboot-registry/ There are a bunch of different places it can be set.